# Embed exe file in a Class library

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exe, class-library

Is it possible to embed an exe file in a class library (dll file)?

I want to use this exe without the necessity of copying it manually to my workstation. In other words, if I want to use my C# class library in another app, I won't need to copy these exe files in a folder and pass the path of this folder in my app.

If there is a way how to do this, it would be great.

---

sorry but what I mean is just, I made a library for screenshots using Selenium Webdriver and when creating a new webdriver object, I need to pass the exe file of the webdriver.
what I need the most is that I don't want to copy the exe file if I will use this library to another workstation for example, I want everything to be packaged as one file 
Thank you

Comment: If this EXE a .NET app you made yourself and have the code for?

Answer (score 2):

Well, *technically* you can embed a binary file as a resource within a DLL (by adding the file as a binary resource through the project properties), but you'll still need to save the file to disk in order to *execute* it (which is assume what you're trying to do) and will possibly have security issues unless your application is fully trusted.

If the binary file is a resource you can extract the bytes from the static `Properties` class:

```
byte[] exe = Properties.Resources.MyExe;
```

and save it to disk like any other byte array.

Comment: Of course, you must have the right to copy it to disk, and the permissions to execute it once it has been copied.

Comment: sorry but what I mean is just, I made a library for screenshots using Selenium Webdriver and when creating a new webdriver object, I need to pass the exe file of the webdriver. what I need the most is that I don't want to copy the exe file if I will use this library in another workstation or another project for example, I want everything to be packaged in one file

Answer (score -1):

If you own the code for the EXE then it would be a lot better for you to turn your EXE code into a library. Then you'll be able to refer to that library from anywhere and call any public functionnality it has. It's a far, far, FAR better approach.

Should you still need to run that code as a standalone process, nothing prevents you from making a new EXE front that will refer to that same library.

Now if you do not have the code, then depending on your deployment strategy you may prefer creating a reusable deployment component / module that can be attached to other application setups.